# Atom and Jupyter can't find SimPy module installed with pip/pip3

Tags: python, pip, atom-editor, conda, simpy

I want to install the SimPy module but when I import it into Atom and/or Jupyter Notebook/Lab it says its not found. When I dod `pip list` it says that it has been installed. I tried installing via `conda install` command but it won't install.

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 7, in <module>
    import simpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simpy'
[Finished in 1.065s]
```

Suggestions?

Comment: What version of simpy do you have? I assume that you are using python3?

Comment: correct - using python 3.7.1

Comment: Do you want simpy or sympy?  I tried "conda install simpy" and it couldn't find simpy. Sympy is a numerical package.

Comment: And what is the simpy version?

Comment: @jmh - i wanted to install simpy to do some simulation modeling. I actually got it to work when I did the manual install from the pypal website and not through `conda install` or `pip install`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

download the files and follow the manual (non cli) method of installation.